# Relax Same Origin Rule for Javascript Widget (deprecated google finance backfill data)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cors, same-origin-policy

**Background:**

I have a small javascript-powered widget that uses data from another origin. I tested it **successfully** in my local IDE using external (non-origin) data from:
https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=.NSEI&x=NSE&i=600&p=1d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v

When I uploaded this widget to my wordpress site I got the error:

> SEC7120: Origin http://www.my-wordpress-site.com not found in
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Which in turn made my calls to the data return something like this:

> SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or
>   null reference

**Disclaimer:**

I know that google finance has long since been deprecated, but my understanding is that the servers were left running. This means that the data is still there. Google clearly states that using the data for consumption violates the terms of usage for this data. What I am building is not an API, or anything consumption related. It's merely a front-end widget serving strictly as aesthetic ornamentation. I just want it to make the site look cooler by plotting some finance data.

Nonetheless, I'm not sure if google is not allowing me to fetch the data because it doesn't recognize my website. Maybe I have misunderstood the terms of use, but I don't *think* I have, but who knows. I'm hoping its a small protocol type of fix where I add a few lines and everything is happily ever after. Alternatively, if it is indeed the other way around, I don't have any control over what domains google trusts and I don't imagine contacting google and saying "hey google, don't leave my website out in the cold" would work.

**Question:** How do I relax the same origin rule? A few similar questions have been asked on stack overflow for c#, but I still wonder how to do this for my wordpress javascript widget. Can javascript alone do it?

I see a lot of examples having:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mozilla.com");
```

I don't know what language that is. I'm guessing PHP or c#. I don't know anything about those languages. I just want to design my widgets without having to learn a billion things about back-end protocols. I'm prepared to put in some effort though.

**Clarification**

I have made widgets this way (pointing an iframe to my widget's html located on my cpanel server where wordpress is in `wp-content/uploads/2018/03`) before and had no trouble at all. This time around I'm getting the origin errors as noted above in my post. The only difference is now I'm using some external data from a google server. Maybe it's google that doesn't recognize my site? The widget worked perfectly offline in my IDE. I'm not sure how to proceed and whether or not word-press has anything to bring to bear for these things to help widget designers like myself out, or if it's another matter altogether.

Error result confirmed in the following browsers:

- edge
- chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fairly straightforward. Browsers enforce the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which prevents sites from accessing data fetched from a foreign domain. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is a protocol that servers can use to instruct browsers to allow foreign domains to read their data.

Public APIs that are intended to be used in a browser context will generally use CORS to make this possible. For whatever reason, Google does not seem to be using CORS to allow public access to this API. In particular, their response does not include the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (part of the CORS protocol) to allow Javascript from your site to read the data. There is really nothing you can do about that.

The standard workaround is to proxy the data. That is, instead of having your code use the API directly, it would instead hit a URL on your server, which would then fetch the requested data from Google and return it. The server will be able to read the data because the Same Origin Policy (being a browser concern) won't apply. And your Javascript will be able to read the result since the request was made to the same domain.

If there are ways to get around the Same Origin Policy in the browser, I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: That helps a lot! After reading your post, I think I would be best off trying to proxy the data. Could you include a reference or a few lines of javascript with an example approach? I can't think of a way to pass the data to my script without having something that directly uses the API. I guess I'm not sure how to have a URL on my server that fetches data.

Comment: @ArashHowaida: It's not really possible to give any sample code because the backend service could be in any language and use any web framework. Fortunately you can find lots of articles (and SO questions) about this approach: https://www.google.com/search?q=same+origin+policy+proxy

Comment: Last follow-up question, by "the backend service could be any language/framework" -- did you mean google's backend or my sites? Or would I need to know the languages/frameworks of both mine and googles? Based on the questions I read, I'm going to try a reverse proxy.

Comment: @ArashHowaida: I mean your backend service doing the proxying. What Google uses is irrelevant, since you consume the API over HTTP. Similarly,the language of the backend service is irrelevant to the Javascript client, since they communicate over HTTP.